# Unable to restart xmonad on archlinux

Tags: arch-linux, x11, xmonad

`xmonad --restart` used to work but it doesn't anymore and it's not a prevalent issue so I think it's probably a problem on my side. I have pasted the output of `strace xmonad --restart` below. I am quite stuck on this one. Any help would be great!

My version of xmonad is 0.11 and I am also using xmonad-contrib.

EDIT:

Did some more digging and it seems the problems is that when I try to restart, I get this error:

`xmonad: executeFile: resource exhausted (Argument list too long)`

```
execve("/usr/bin/xmonad", ["xmonad", "--restart"], [/* 43 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x1f88000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=134930, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 134930, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f7fceec6000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/usr/lib/librt.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\360\"\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=31760, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f7fceec5000
mmap(NULL, 2128912, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f7fceabe000
mprotect(0x7f7fceac5000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f7fcecc4000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x6000) = 0x7f7fcecc4000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/usr/lib/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\320\16\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=14672, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2109712, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f7fce8ba000
mprotect(0x7f7fce8bd000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f7fceabc000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x2000) = 0x7f7fceabc000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/usr/lib/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\300`\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=138242, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2208912, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f7fce69e000
mprotect(0x7f7fce6b5000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f7fce8b4000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x16000) = 0x7f7fce8b4000
mmap(0x7f7fce8b6000, 13456, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f7fce8b6000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/usr/lib/libXinerama.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\240\v\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=10392, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f7fceec4000
mmap(NULL, 2105672, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f7fce49b000
mprotect(0x7f7fce49d000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f7fce69c000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1000) = 0x7f7fce69c000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/usr/lib/libX11.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\200\335\1\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1314936, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 3412192, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f7fce159000
mprotect(0x7f7fce294000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f7fce493000, 28672, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x13a000) = 0x7f7fce493000
mmap(0x7f7fce49a000, 224, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f7fce49a000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/usr/lib/libXrandr.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\340\34\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=39184, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2134472, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f7fcdf4f000
mprotect(0x7f7fcdf58000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f7fce157000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x8000) = 0x7f7fce157000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/usr/lib/libgmp.so.10", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\0\314\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=488208, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f7fceec3000
mmap(NULL, 2583424, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f7fcdcd8000
mprotect(0x7f7fcdd4e000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f7fcdf4d000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x75000) = 0x7f7fcdf4d000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/usr/lib/libm.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\200U\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1067456, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 3162456, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f7fcd9d3000
mprotect(0x7f7fcdad6000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f7fcdcd6000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x103000) = 0x7f7fcdcd6000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/usr/lib/libffi.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\0\31\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=31056, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2127464, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f7fcd7cb000
mprotect(0x7f7fcd7d2000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f7fcd9d1000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x6000) = 0x7f7fcd9d1000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/usr/lib/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0`\1\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1984416, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f7fceec2000
mmap(NULL, 3813200, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f7fcd428000
mprotect(0x7f7fcd5c1000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f7fcd7c1000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x199000) = 0x7f7fcd7c1000
mmap(0x7f7fcd7c7000, 16208, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f7fcd7c7000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/usr/lib/libXext.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0p9\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=73688, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2169560, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f7fcd216000
mprotect(0x7f7fcd227000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f7fcd426000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x10000) = 0x7f7fcd426000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/usr/lib/libxcb.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0@\244\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=137968, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2233352, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f7fccff4000
mprotect(0x7f7fcd015000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f7fcd214000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x20000) = 0x7f7fcd214000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/usr/lib/libXrender.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\360\33\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=39376, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f7fceec1000
mmap(NULL, 2134664, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f7fccdea000
mprotect(0x7f7fccdf3000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f7fccff2000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x8000) = 0x7f7fccff2000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/usr/lib/libXau.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0 \17\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=14512, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2109744, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f7fccbe6000
mprotect(0x7f7fccbe8000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f7fccde8000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x2000) = 0x7f7fccde8000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/usr/lib/libXdmcp.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0p\24\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=22664, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2117888, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f7fcc9e0000
mprotect(0x7f7fcc9e5000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f7fccbe4000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x4000) = 0x7f7fccbe4000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f7fceec0000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f7fceebf000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f7fceebe000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f7fceebd000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f7fceebe700) = 0
mprotect(0x7f7fcd7c1000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f7fccbe4000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f7fccde8000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f7fceabc000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f7fcd214000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f7fce493000, 8192, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f7fccff2000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f7fcd426000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f7fcd9d1000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f7fcdcd6000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f7fcdf4d000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f7fce157000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f7fce69c000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f7fce8b4000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f7fcecc4000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x796000, 4096, PROT_READ)     = 0
mprotect(0x7f7fceee7000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7f7fceec6000, 134930)          = 0
set_tid_address(0x7f7fceebe9d0)         = 14442
set_robust_list(0x7f7fceebe9e0, 24)     = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRTMIN, {0x7f7fce6a3b90, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_SIGINFO, 0x7f7fce6ae200}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_1, {0x7f7fce6a3c20, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, 0x7f7fce6ae200}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [RTMIN RT_1], NULL, 8) = 0
getrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, {rlim_cur=8192*1024, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x1f88000
brk(0x1fa9000)                          = 0x1fa9000
open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1607712, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 1607712, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f7fced34000
close(3)                                = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, {0, 1686252}) = 0
open("/proc/meminfo", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f7fceee6000
read(3, "MemTotal:        8120128 kB\nMemF"..., 1024) = 1024
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x7f7fceee6000, 4096)            = 0
mmap(NULL, 2097152, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f7fcc7e0000
munmap(0x7f7fcc7e0000, 131072)          = 0
munmap(0x7f7fcc900000, 917504)          = 0
timer_create(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {(nil), SIGVTALRM, SIGEV_SIGNAL, {...}}, {0}) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGVTALRM, {0x549510, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7f7fce6ae200}, NULL, 8) = 0
timer_settime(0, 0, {it_interval={0, 10000000}, it_value={0, 10000000}}, NULL) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {0x550a40, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f7fce6ae200}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, NULL, {0x550a40, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f7fce6ae200}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {0x550a40, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f7fcd45b9f0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGPIPE, {0x5509d0, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f7fce6ae200}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTSTP, {0x550a60, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f7fce6ae200}, NULL, 8) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, {0, 1868855}) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [INT], [], 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {0x550ae0, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESETHAND|SA_SIGINFO, 0x7f7fce6ae200}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [PIPE], [], 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGPIPE, {SIG_IGN, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f7fce6ae200}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [], 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGCHLD, {SIG_IGN, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f7fce6ae200}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
wait4(-1, 0x7f7fcc806010, WNOHANG, NULL) = -1 ECHILD (No child processes)
socket(PF_LOCAL, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC, 0) = 3
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_LOCAL, sun_path=@"/tmp/.X11-unix/X0"}, 20) = 0
getpeername(3, {sa_family=AF_LOCAL, sun_path=@"/tmp/.X11-unix/X0"}, [20]) = 0
uname({sys="Linux", node="imac-archlinux", ...}) = 0
access("/home/mtahmed/.Xauthority", R_OK) = 0
open("/home/mtahmed/.Xauthority", O_RDONLY) = 4
fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0600, st_size=119, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f7fceee6000
read(4, "\1\0\0\16imac-archlinux\0\0010\0\22MIT-MAGIC"..., 4096) = 119
read(4, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(4)                                = 0
munmap(0x7f7fceee6000, 4096)            = 0
getsockname(3, {sa_family=AF_LOCAL, NULL}, [2]) = 0
fcntl(3, F_GETFL)                       = 0x2 (flags O_RDWR)
fcntl(3, F_SETFL, O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK)    = 0
fcntl(3, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 4294967295) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLOUT}])
writev(3, [{"l\0\v\0\0\0\22\0\20\0\0\0", 12}, {"", 0}, {"MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1", 18}, {"\0\0", 2}, {"\244T(\352\32Z\265E\270\325\3358G\343\34&", 16}, {"", 0}], 6) = 48
recvfrom(3, 0x1f99120, 8, 0, 0, 0)      = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}], 1, 4294967295) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLIN}])
recvfrom(3, "\1\0\v\0\0\0\213\5", 8, 0, NULL, NULL) = 8
recvfrom(3, "h\4\261\0\0\0`\1\377\377\37\0\0\1\0\0\24\0\377\377\1\7\0\0  \10\377\0\0\0\0"..., 5676, 0, NULL, NULL) = 5676
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 4294967295) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLOUT}])
writev(3, [{"b\0\5\0\f\0\0\0BIG-REQUESTS", 20}], 1) = 20
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}], 1, 4294967295) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLIN}])
recvmsg(3, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"\1\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\1\205\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 4096}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 32
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 4294967295) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLOUT}])
writev(3, [{"\205\0\1\0", 4}], 1)       = 4
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}], 1, 4294967295) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLIN}])
recvmsg(3, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"\1\0\2\0\0\0\0\0\377\377?\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 4096}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 32
recvmsg(3, 0x7fff5a492470, 0)           = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 4294967295) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLOUT}])
writev(3, [{"7\0\5\0\0\0`\1\210\2\0\0\10\0\0\0\377\377\377\0\24\0\6\0\210\2\0\0\27\0\0\0"..., 44}, {NULL, 0}, {"", 0}], 3) = 44
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}], 1, 4294967295) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLIN}])
recvmsg(3, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"\1\10\4\0\223\1\0\0\37\0\0\0\0\0\0\0K\6\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 1644
recvmsg(3, 0x7fff5a4924b0, 0)           = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 4294967295) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLOUT}])
writev(3, [{"b\0\5\0\t\0`\1", 8}, {"XKEYBOARD", 9}, {"\0\0\0", 3}], 3) = 20
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}], 1, 4294967295) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLIN}])
recvmsg(3, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"\1\0\5\0\0\0\0\0\1\207U\211\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 4096}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 32
recvmsg(3, 0x7fff5a492380, 0)           = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
recvmsg(3, 0x7fff5a492380, 0)           = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 4294967295) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLOUT}])
writev(3, [{"\207\0\2\0\1\0\0\0", 8}, {NULL, 0}, {"", 0}], 3) = 8
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}], 1, 4294967295) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLIN}])
recvmsg(3, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"\1\1\6\0\0\0\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 4096}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 32
recvmsg(3, 0x7fff5a492430, 0)           = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
recvmsg(3, 0x7fff5a492430, 0)           = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 4294967295) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLOUT}])
writev(3, [{"\20\0\6\0\16\0\0\0XMONAD_RESTART\6\0", 24}, {NULL, 0}, {"", 0}], 3) = 24
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}], 1, 4294967295) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLIN}])
recvmsg(3, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"\1\0\7\0\0\0\0\0>\2\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 4096}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 32
recvmsg(3, 0x7fff5a492540, 0)           = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
recvmsg(3, 0x7fff5a492540, 0)           = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 4294967295) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLOUT}])
writev(3, [{"\31\0\v\0\210\2\0\0\0\0\2\0! \0\0\210\2\0\0>\2\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 48}, {NULL, 0}, {"", 0}], 3) = 48
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN}], 1, 4294967295) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLIN}])
recvmsg(3, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"\1\1\t\0\0\0\0\0\373\1@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 4096}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 32
recvmsg(3, 0x7fff5a492560, 0)           = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
recvmsg(3, 0x7fff5a492560, 0)           = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, {0, 2476563}) = 0
ioctl(1, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or SNDRV_TIMER_IOCTL_NEXT_DEVICE or TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [INT], [], 8) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, {0, 2508552}) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID, {0, 2512002}) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
timer_settime(0, 0, {it_interval={0, 0}, it_value={0, 0}}, NULL) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGVTALRM, {SIG_IGN, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_INTERRUPT|SA_NODEFER|SA_RESETHAND, 0x7f7fcd45b9f0}, {0x549510, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7f7fce6ae200}, 8) = 0
timer_delete(0)                         = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [TTOU], [], 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f7fce6ae200}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGPIPE, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f7fce6ae200}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTSTP, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f7fce6ae200}, NULL, 8) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, {0, 2642044}) = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Comment: It exits without error, so how do you see it didn't work ? Do you get any error messages ?

Comment: Well, it didn't reload the config and that's how I know it didn't work. I don't see the config changes. Please see the edit.

Comment: The first google result for that error is the module [XMonad.Actions.WorkspaceCursors](http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad-contrib/XMonad-Actions-WorkspaceCursors.html) : "TODO ... : restoring xmonad's state results in: xmonad: executeFile: resource exhausted (Argument list too long) when you specify more than about 50 workspaces." If that's not your problem, you'll need to post your xmonad.hs.

Comment: This is my problem. I just don't know how to fix it. I only have 10 workspaces though and not that many windows open when I try to restart.

Comment: If you have other layout modifiers, it adds to the size ... Because XMonad keeps the state by passing it as argument when it restart, ultimately there is a limit. But it's difficult to say what is making you hit the limit with only 10 workspaces without seeing your configuration ...

Comment: @Leiaz http://sprunge.us/gLKL?hs

Comment: I just tried removing a bunch of stuff from my config that I don't use anymore and it seems to be working fine again. Is there a way to *actually* fix this problem?

Comment: In the general case, rewrite XMonad so it will pass its state in some other way ? There is a system limit to the size of arguments passed to a execv call, data isn't usually passed as argument... In the case of your config you could try removing from your layout hook  the useless `onWorkspace` that lead to "allLayouts" and use `onWorkspaces` to group the workspaces that will have the same layouts, to save a little bit of space ... (You should edit your question with your config and the actual problem, perhaps someone will have a better idea).